# How to set Auto Increment Values in asp.net, sql server

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a table and with a primary key called `OrderNo`.

However, I want the `OrderNo` be auto increment as well.

How can I do in the following format?

```
"ABC201320001", "ABC201320002", "ABC201320003", ............ etc.
```

Here ABC is My Company Name(Default),
2013 is Current Year,
2 is the age of my Company
and 0001 is the Document No(Running Number)

Here the auto increment(ABC0001,ABC0002,...) is working good... but the problem is how to get current year(2013,..) and age of my company(2,..) increments based on the current year changes to next year.

Is there a way I can do this in SQL Server?

Comment: can you give some example?

Answer (score 3):

Use an `IDENTITY` and a computed column

```
CREATE TABLE Tablename (
 ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
 ...
 ...
 /*gives 000-999. Change the RIGHT as needed to give more*/
 PIC_ID AS 'PIC' + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(ID as varchar(10)), 3)

 CONSTRAINT PK_name PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PIC_ID)
 )
```

You can change the RIGHT to cover as many digits as needed, or you may not want leading zeroes:

```
 PIC_ID AS 'PIC' + CAST(ID as varchar(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would look like this:

```
create table tablename
(
  ID int identity (0000, 1),
  PIC_ID as 'PIC'+right('0000'+cast(ID as varchar(5)), 5) persisted,
  constraint PK_tablename primary key (ID)
)
```